# Strange behaviour of find when passing variable parameters

Tags: bash, find, quotes, quoting

I created a file called `foo bar` (with the command `touch foo\ bar`).

Then, in Bash I tried the following commands:

```
s='"foo bar"'; find $s
s='"foo bar"'; find "$s"
s="foo bar"; find "$s"
```

With the first one, `find` looks for files named `"foo` and then for files named `bar"`.

With the second one, `find` looks for files named `"foo bar"`.

Both commands fail: `find` does not find any file.

Finally the third command has the expected behaviour: `find` looks for `foo bar` and shows it.

I know it is bad practice not to escape the space character, but can anyone explain me what is going on here? Why doesn't the second command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it is bad practice not to escape the space character, but can
>   anyone explain me what is going on here? **Why doesn't the second
>   command work?**

Because you are looking for something called `"foo bar"`. You quoted too much :)

By saying:

```
s='"foo bar"'
```

you indicate that the variable `$s` is in fact `"foo bar"`. That is, the quotes *belong* in the variable content.

- When you say:

  ```
  find "$s"
  ```

you are trying to find those files whose name is exactly `"foo bar"`, with the quotes. Then, if we create a file with this exactly name, it will work:

```
$ touch '"foo bar"'
$ s='"foo bar"'; find "$s"
"foo bar"
```

- When you say:

  ```
  $ s='"foo bar"'; find $s
  find: ‘"foo’: No such file or directory
  find: ‘bar"’: No such file or directory
  ```

You are in fact saying:

```
$ find \"foo bar\"
find: ‘"foo’: No such file or directory
find: ‘bar"’: No such file or directory
```

That is, you are using `find` together with two arguments: `"foo` or `bar"`. And neither of these files exist. But, again, if you create one of them, voilà!

```
$ touch '"foo'
$ find \"foo bar\"
"foo
find: ‘bar"’: No such file or directory
```

Note the behaviour of `find X Y` is to look for `X` and `Y`:

```
$ find a b
find: ‘a’: No such file or directory
find: ‘b’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: So the only way to pass a variable parameter with quotes (as if I were typing the entire command without variables) is to surround the variable with them: "$s", otherwise they become ordinary characters, right?

Comment: Mmm I don't know if I understand what you mean. What for sure you have to be careful is not to over-quote :) The name you are looking for is `foo bar`, not `"foo bar"`, hence assign it like this. That is, if you are looking for something being `foo bar`, just assign the variable normally `var="foo bar"` so that the quotes just indicate that the variable is `foo bar`. Then, use `find` with double quotes to make sure the variable is being interpreted as a whole and unique string: `find "$var"`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What I meant is that (if I have understood) when Bash expands a variable he treats the quotes contained in it as ordinary characters, and no longer as symbols telling him to group together the words..

Comment: Exactly, that's it! You explained it way better than I did.